# how to add data from text file and Sort this data data received from text file using fileInputStream

Tags: java, collections

i want that  i should read some text from a text file using file inputstream..and then store this data using set or get method..and now SORT  this data using arraylist...

Class SongDetail  will be used to set values of song,movieName and artist....
there is a text file "text1.txt" who had store song/movieName/artist details...
now i want that when i read this file in Class1,String reurned will be splited into song,movieName,artist and this is set in songDetail class.

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.*; 
  public class Class1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  //ArrayList <String>list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  ArrayList <String>list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

   try
   {
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("text1.txt");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String strLine;

     while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
       {
      // System.out.println(strLine);
  list.add(strLine);

   //System.out.print(list);
     }



 System.out.print(list);

      Collections.sort(list);

      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
         }







 class SongDetail
 {
 private String song;
 private String movieName;
  private String artist;

 public SongDetail
  {
 }

   public void setSong(String song) throws InvalidSongException
        {
            this.song=song;

                    {
                    throw new InvalidSongException();
        }           }

    public void setMovieName(String movieName) 
{
this.movieName=movieName;
}


    public void setArtist(String artist) throws InvalidArtistException

        {
    this.artist=artist;

                    {
                             throw new InvalidMarkException();
                    }

                }

     public String getSong()
{
return song;
}

  public String getMovieName() 
{
return movieName;
}

   public String getArtist() 
{
return artist;

}



   }
```

Comment: Needs a clear question

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? The code works fine although you should close your BufferedReader after the while loop with:

```
br.close();
```

Your list isn't printed alphabetically because you print it out before you sort it. Changing the following two lines should solve your problem:

```
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.print(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing before sort

add System.out.print(list); at last line of try block